# Correct kernel for blur filter

Tags: c++, opencv

I am attempting to use my own kernel to blur an image (for educational purposes). But my kernel just makes my whole image white. Is my blur kernel correct? I believe the proper name of the blur filter I am trying to apply is a normalised blur.

```
void blur_img(const Mat& src, Mat& output) { 
    // src is a 1 channel CV_8UC1

    float kdata[] = { 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f,   0.125f, 0.25f, 0.125f, 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f };
    //float kdata[] = { -1,-1,-1,  -1,8,-1,  -1,-1,-1}; // outline filter works fine
    Mat kernel(3, 3, CV_32F, kdata);

    // results in output being a completely white image
    filter2D(src, output, CV_32F, kernel);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is not white, is float. I am sure you that you are displaying the image with `imshow` in a later place, and it looks all white. This is explained in the [`imshow` documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#imshow). Specifically:

> If the image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied
>   by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

This means that if it is float it has  to be [0,1] values to be displayed correctly.

Now, that we know what cause it, lets see how to solve it. I can think of 3 possible ways:

**1)** `normalize` the image to [0,1]

```
cv::Mat dst;
cv::normalize(outputFromBlur, dst, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
```

This function normalizes the values, so it may shift the colors... this is not the best one for known images, but rather for depth maps or other matrices with values of unknown colors.

**2)** `covertTo` uchar:

```
cv::Mat dst;
outputFromBlur.convertTo(dst, CV_8U);
```

This function does saturate_cast, so it may handle possible overflow/underflow.

**3)** use `filter2D` with another output depth:

```
cv::filter2D(src, output, -1, kernel);
```

With -1 the desire output will be of the same type of the source (I assume your source is CV_8U)

I hope this helps you, if not leave a comment.